# How to find the size of array?

Tags: java

In java, suppose we have

> int[] a=new int[4];

then how can we find the length/size of a?a.size() and a.length() are not working.

Comment: That's because it's `a.length`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth thnx

Comment: It si **built-in length property** of array to determine the size of any array. It's not a **method** of array.

Answer (score 2):

Use `a.length` to find the length of an array. This is not a method and that is why `a.length()` does not work. `a.length()` is for Strings though.